# Bootstrap group element inline when navbar collapsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these two links here that act as buttons. They are basic glyphicons.[image] This is when the navbar isn't collapsed into xs view.
But when the navbar is collapsed the links are each on one row which is the normal bootstrap comportement. [image]

So my question is :

Is it possible to make both arrows/links inline like the in the non-collapsed navbar. If so how?

This is my code for the ul in the navbar-right section.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
          <li><a id="minicalendar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></a></li>
          <li><a id="linkToday">Today</a></li>
          <li><a id="btnPrev" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></a></li> 
          <li><a id="btnNext" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></a></li>
          <li><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" type="button" id="btnHelp"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/t21t416e/)**

Comment: Perhaps you can create a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: Try using http://www.bootply.com/ to recreate your issue, then post a link to your saved Bootply. That way, we can debug a working example of the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/t21t416e/

Comment: isherwood was kind enough to provide this jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/t21t416e/ I can post the rest of the navbar but it is pretty useless as the problem is visible with just the right side of the code

Comment: Ignore my last comment (deleted), I guess I just misunderstood the question. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
.menu-half {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 48%;
}

<li class="menu-half">...</li>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/t21t416e/6)**

You can use 50% if you mash the two LI tags together. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/t21t416e/5)**

Comment: That is perfect thank you! I removed the width and it works exactly how I wanted it with my css!